# Finding the constant coefficients for the nth derivative of the Standard Normal Moment Generating Function

Tags: probability, recurrence-relations

The Moment Generating Function for a Standard Normal $X\sim\mathcal{N}(0,1)$ looks like so:

$$M_X(s) = \text{exp}(\frac{s^2}{2})$$

Usually we are interested in finding the $n^{th}$ moment of $X$, so we end up taking the $n^{th}$ derivative of $M_X(s)$ with $s$ evaluated at zero. However I am more curious as to what the final form of the polynomial $\frac{d^n}{ds^n} M_X(s)$ looks like.

Through taking success derivatives we know our polynomial should be of the form:

$$p_n(s) = \sum_{i=0}^{n} a_{i}^{(n)}s^i\text{exp}(\frac{s^2}{2})$$

Where $p_n$ is the $n^{th}$ derivative of $M_X(s)$

From the relation $p_{n+1} = \frac{d}{ds} p_n$ we obtain the following recurrence relation:

$$a_i^{(n+1)} = (i+1)a_{i+1}^{(n)} + a_{i-1}^{(n)} \hspace{1cm} \text{ with } a_i^{(n)} = 0 \text{ for } i \notin [0,1,\ldots,n]$$

The initial condition would be $a_0^{(0)} = 1$

How can I go about solving this recurrence relation?

Answer (score 1):

$e^{\frac {s^{2}} 2} =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac  {(s^{2})^{n}} {2^{n} n!}$. For any convergent power series $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} a_n s^{n}$ the n-th derivative at $0$ is simply $(n!)a_n$. Can you write down the values of the n-th derivatives now?

[ $\frac {d^{k}} {ds^{k}} M_X(s)=\sum_{n\geq k/2} \frac {(2n)(2n-1)\cdots (2n-k+1) s^{2n-k}} {2^{n} n!}].$

Comment: Hi Kavi thanks for the insight. With your suggestion I believe I can get the $a_0^{(n)}$ terms for all $n$. Is there a slight modification I can make to get the rest of the $a_i^{(n)}$ terms for a given $i,n$?

Comment: @Luciano I have edited the answer.